# Joomla 3.0 installation database creating issue

Tags: joomla, installation

I try to install Joomla 3 in my system. After download and extract files I put files in my localhost folder `wamp/www/jesite/myfiles`. After that I run the jesite folder and it displays index page then I give the corresponding details in configuration, database and overview section.

Then I pressed install button after it shows a window with four section

First it completed Backing up old databases and then it shows progress bar in creating database tables. But after that it shows the progress bar for a long time and when I checked in DB it creates 78 tables. But after it shows only the progress bar.

I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is this on MySQL and on apache2?

Comment: 78 Tables is a strange number to have. I take it that you are backing up an old set? Of the 78 tables does that include the full backup? Can you use another database and try doing it without backing up the old tables?

Comment: Also tried with remove old db but it is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I change php.ini

from

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

to

```
max_execution_time = 3000
```

also bumped up

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Answer (score 5):

**Replacing "ENGINE=InnoDB" by "ENGINE=MyIsam"** in the SQL script **/installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql** also **worked for me**, as [Giorgi BaneTishvili suggested in the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18617746/2779877).

I was installing Joomla 3.1.5 in a Strato shared hosting by uploading Joomla files, not using their auto-installing apps.

I tried adding a php.ini file with *max_execution_time = 3000* and *memory_limit = 256M*, but it did not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the SQL install file (`Root/installation/SQL/mysql/joomla.sql`). Open with notepad and replace all `"ENGINE=InnoDB"` with `"ENGINE=MyIsam"` the DB type then it will work succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Go to \installation\sql\mysql\joomla.sql and change all ENGINE=InnoDB to ENGINE=MyIsam

Answer (score 1):

Edit the SQL install file (`Root/installation/SQL/mysql/joomla.sql`). Open with notepad and replace all `"ENGINE=InnoDB"` with `"ENGINE=MyIsam"` the DB type then it will work successfully.

This answer has helped me a lot, Joomla works no after a long search, although I still don't now why I had to make this change in the script, does the original script work well with other users how implement Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

changing max_execution_time = 30 to 3000 worked for me for Wampserver 2.4

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue i changed the data base password and removed the special characters, MySqli is an improved version on MySql driver so it is not recommended to change this value on the configuration, also changing to MyIsam removes the integrity of the relations and transactions, so this is also a point of considering. So if your server supports MySqli you should use this option with the default InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

Just set (at php.ini)

```
max_execution_time = 120
```

works for me, on Xwampp v3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue as well, to fix:

1. Open file `installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql`
2. Replace **`ENGINE=InnoDb`** to **`ENGINE=MyIsam`**

And it works successfully.