# Joomla main configuration step loading time

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

So I'm trying to install Joomla onto a web server and I get to the installation page. The first step is the configuration of the website and administration details. I fill that out and click next but it is taking ages for it to go onto the next step. I have done it locally before and it went to the next step straight away so I think I may be missing something?

Comment: Your issue sounds similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291384/joomla-3-0-installation-database-creating-issue)

Comment: Is this the latest version of Joomla 3 (3.2.3) - also what browser are you using?

Comment: Only problem with the answer in that link is, changing the max execution time and memory limit doesn't solve the actual long loading times. Not sure why people also recommend MyISAM instead of InnoDB

Comment: Using chrome and yes it is the latest version, think it has something to do with making a database with the file host?

Comment: Have your tried downloading another Joomla installation package, maybe the archive was corrupt.